# Sum of a block of duplicated rows, if not duplicated add 1 and calculate difference

Tags: awk, sum, duplicates

I need to parse several sorted files that have the following structure:

```
1_0.91  10
1_0.91  20
1_0.91  30
1_0.91  40
2_0.89  50
1_0.91  60
1_0.91  70
1_0.91  80
2_0.89  90
2_0.89  100
2_0.89  110
3_0.86  120
```

The first column is a feature in the genome, and the second column is their location. Each feature is interspaced with others. I want to find the size of each feature or blocks of each feature. For this example, my desired output is the following:

```
1_0.91  10  40  30
2_0.89  50  51  1
1_0.91  60  80  20
2_0.89  90  110 20
3_0.86  120 121 1
```

The feature 1_0.91 starts at 10 and is found on locations 20, 30, and 40. I want to create a new column with the start and end. In this case, starts at 10 and ends at 40. Then output their size in a new column (end minus start, in this case, 30). There are several places where I have each feature only once. In my example, 2_0.89 is between blocks of feature 1_0.91. In this case, I want to add 1 to the current value and estimate the size as well, which in this case, equals 1.

I have tried to use awk, but I am stuck with the features that appear only once.

Here is what I used so far. It is a bit convoluted:
Let's call the first file file1.txt:

```
cat file1.txt | awk '$1!=prev{if (pline){print pline;}print;}{prev=$1;pline=$0;}END{print pline;}' > file2.txt
```

The output:

```
1_0.91  10
1_0.91  40
2_0.89  50
2_0.89  50
1_0.91  60
1_0.91  80
2_0.89  90
2_0.89  110
3_0.86  120
3_0.86  120
```

Now, I print the odd and even lines with sed, then I use paste to place the files together:

```
paste <(cat file2.txt | sed 'n; d') <(cat file2.txt | sed '1d; n; d' ) | awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {print $1,$2,$4}' > file3.txt
```

The output:

```
1_0.91  10  40
2_0.89  50  50
1_0.91  60  80
2_0.89  90  110
3_0.86  120 120
```

Next, I estimate the size of each feature:

```
cat file3.txt | awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {print $1,$2,$3,$3-$2}' > file4.txt
```

The output:

```
1_0.91  10  40  30
2_0.89  50  50  0
1_0.91  60  80  20
2_0.89  90  110 20
3_0.86  120 120 0
```

Next, I replace zeros in column 4 with 1:

```
cat file4.txt | awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} { $4 = ($4 == "0" ? 1 : $4) } 1' > file5.txt
```

The output:

```
1_0.91  10  40  30
2_0.89  50  50  1
1_0.91  60  80  20
2_0.89  90  110 20
3_0.86  120 120 1
```

Finally, I fix the end of each feature with awk:

```
cat file5.txt | awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} { $3 = ($2 == $3 ? $3+1 : $3) } 1' > file6.txt
```

The output:

```
1_0.91  10  40  30
2_0.89  50  51  1
1_0.91  60  80  20
2_0.89  90  110 20
3_0.86  120 121 1
```

I wonder if there was a faster and easy way to do it.
Thank you.

Comment: Why awk? Can you use e.g. python for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumptions:

- consecutive lines with the same feature (field #1) are sorted by location (field #2) in ascending order
- input/output field delimiters are `\t`
- location (field #2) values are always positive integers (otherwise we could tweak the code)

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
function print_feature() {
    if ( feature != "" )
       print feature,min,max,(max-min)
}

BEGIN         { FS=OFS="\t" }
$1 != feature { print_feature()          # row contains a new/different feature, so print previous feature details
                feature=$1
                min=$2
                max=min+1
                next
              }
              { max=$2 }                 # row contains a repeated/duplicate feature
END           { print_feature() }        # flush last feature details to stdout
' feature.dat
```

This generates:

```
1_0.91  10      40      30
2_0.89  50      51      1
1_0.91  60      80      20
2_0.89  90      110     20
3_0.86  120     121     1
```

Comment: Thank you. Much more elegant this way.